# Datagridview and access database only updates after clicking a different row

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I am reading an access database and populating the info in datagridview. My form has a DGV, and 3 buttons. 
Button one copies the selected row to a datetimepicker control. 
Button two copied the updated datetimepicker value back to the DVG
Button three does an update (writes the info back to the database).

My issue is that the info only gets updated in the database if I select a different row before hitting button three. I am not getting any error message in either case.

Below is my code. The database only has 2 columns (name and DOB - which is date/time).

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim dbConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim sDataset As New DataSet
    Dim sDataAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    Dim iTotalRows As Integer
    Dim sShipTypeFilter As String
    Dim sBuildingFilter As String
    Dim sCustSuppFilter As String
    Dim sStatusFilter As String
    Dim sDayFilter As String
    Dim dv As New DataView


    Sub myDBConn()
        dbConn.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\terry\Documents\Database1.accdb"

        Debug.Print("Start:" & DateAndTime.Now.ToString)

        dbConn.Open()
        sql = "select * from TableX"
        sDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, dbConn)
        sDataAdapter.Fill(sDataset, "MyTable")
        dbConn.Close()
        iTotalRows = sDataset.Tables("MyTable").Rows.Count
        Debug.Print("Rows from Access:" & iTotalRows)

        Debug.Print("End:" & DateAndTime.Now.ToString)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Call myDBConn()

        Debug.Print("DVG1 row count before binding:" & DataGridView1.Rows.Count)
        'dv = New DataView(sDataset.Tables(0), "Shipment = 'Regular' and Building = 'CSE'", "Company DESC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
        dv = sDataset.Tables(0).DefaultView
        Debug.Print("DataView count:" & dv.Count)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dv

        Debug.Print("DVG1 Rows:" & DataGridView1.Rows.Count)
        DataGridView1.Columns("DOB").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm tt"

        DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        dtp1.Value = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("DOB").Value
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("DOB").Value = dtp1.Value
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Debug.Print("switched row")
        Me.Visible = False
        Dim sqlcb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(sDataAdapter)
        sDataAdapter.Update(sDataset.Tables("MyTable"))
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - thanks Stef for putting me on the right track.
My DGV is only updated programmatically (not by user edits) so I updated the code for button 2 to set the editmode, begin editing, update the selected DVG row and end editing:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    DataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically
    DataGridView1.BeginEdit(True)
    DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("DOB").Value = dtp1.Value
    DataGridView1.EndEdit()
End Sub
```

After doing this modification - my datadapter.update command works!!

Answer (score 0):

Before updating you need to Endedit. This means you need to add Endedit for the datagridview.

So this will be your code:

```
Debug.Print("switched row")
Me.Visible = False
Dim sqlcb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(sDataAdapter)
Datagridview1.EndEdit() 
sDataAdapter.Update(sDataset.Tables("MyTable"))
Me.Close()
```

EDIT1:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable        

    dbConn.Open()
    sDataset.Tables.Add(dt)
    sDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from TableX", dbConn)
    sDataAdapter.Update(dt)
    dbConn.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Stef. I tried adding the Datagridview1.EndEdit() but it does not fix the issue. The modification still does not appear in the database unless I click a different row before clicking the update button.

Comment: No it didn't work. Even if I click on a different row and hit the button, there were no writes to the database.